# Mingw32 std::isnan with -ffast-math

Tags: g++, mingw32, fast-math

I am compiling the following code with the `-ffast-math` option:

```
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::isnan(std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN() ) << std::endl;
}
```

I am getting 0 as output. How can my code tell whether a floating point number is NaN when it is compiled with `-ffast-math`?

Note: On linux, std::isnan works even with -ffast-math.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `-ffast-math` instructs GCC not to handle `NaN`s, it is expected that `isnan()` has an undefined behaviour. Returning `0` is therefore valid.

You can use the following fast replacement for `isnan()`:

```
#if defined __FAST_MATH__
#   undef isnan
#endif
#if !defined isnan
#   define isnan isnan
#   include <stdint.h>
static inline int isnan(float f)
{
    union { float f; uint32_t x; } u = { f };
    return (u.x << 1) > 0xff000000u;
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

On linux, the gcc flag `-ffast-math` breaks `isnan()`, `isinf()` and `isfinite()` - there may be other related functions that are also broken that I have not tested.

The trick of wrapping the function/macro in parentheses also did not work (ie. `(isnan)(x)`)

Removing `-ffast-math` works ;-)