# Good sentinel value for double if prefer to use -ffast-math

Tags: c, optimization, double, nan, fast-math

Since the `gcc` option `-ffast-math` effectively disables `NaN` and `-/+inf`, I'm looking for maybe the next best option for representing `NaN` in my performance-critical math code.  Ideally the sentinel value if operated on (add, mul, div, sub, etc..) would yield the sentinel value as `NaN` would do but I doubt this would be possible since I think `NaN` is the only value that accomplishes this.  `-0.0` might not be a good fit as it's also disabled in `-ffast-math` and could prevent certain optimizations like `(x+0.0)`, etc..

Perhaps my question should rather be, is there any way to use `NaN` or some other "special double" while being able to enable a lot of the math optimizations without breaking down?

System is `Linux/x64, gcc 4.8.1`.

Comment: This thread may be helpful [Mingw32 std::isnan with -ffast-math](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263404/mingw32-stdisnan-with-ffast-math)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Thanks, that thread is helpful.

Comment: There is also the option of using `-fno-finite-math-only -ftrapping-math` http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2009-04/msg00091.html

Comment: I've similarly been wondering about good sentinels for functions returning floating point values. I decided to go with using `optional` as in `optional<float>` or `optional<double>`. Besides making the intention explicit, I think this also has the advantage of being less sensitive to compiler options like for fast math. This of course requires C++17, or using `boost::optional` or writing ones own implementation of `optional` (which is what I did and that seemed easy to me).

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a value which would be propagated by arithmetic operations, `NaN` is still available with option `-ffast-math`. The problem lies somewhere else. With `-ffast-math` some operations can removed from the computation due to optimization, and then there is no way to guarantee `NaN` or any other value would be propagates.

For example, the following, with `-ffast-math` set, will cause hard writing `0.0` into `n` and there is no special value for `n` which would protect from it.

```
float n = NAN;
n *= 0.0;
```

One thing you can do, is to use `-fno-finite-math-only -ftrapping-math` with `-ffast-math` as Shafik Yaghmour said. And the other is, if there are only few places where you expect a bad value, you can check for it by yourself putting tests exactly in those points.

The last option I can think -- if you really badly need optimization -- is to manually inject `NaN` (and maybe `inf`) values into the computation and check for how long it is propagated. Then in those places where the propagation stops, test for `NaN` (`inf`) occurrence. -- This is an unsafe method, as I am not one hundred percent sure, can `-ffast-math` involve conditional flow of operations. If it can, there is a significant chance, this solution will be invalid. So it is risky and if chosen needs very heavy testing covering all branches of the computation.

Normally I would be rather against the last solution, but actually there is a chance, `NaN` (`inf`) values will be propagated though the whole computation or almost whole, so it can give the performance you are seeking for. So you may want to take the risk.

---

Checking for `NaN` with `-ffast-math` you can do, as Shafik Yaghmour said, with

```
inline int isnan(float f)
{
    union { float f; uint32_t x; } u = { f };
    return (u.x << 1) > 0xff000000u;
}
```

and for `double` with

```
inline int isnan(double d)
{
    union { double d; uint64_t x; } u = { d };
    return (u.x << 1) > 0xff70000000000000ull;
}
```

Checking for `inf` would be

```
inline int isinf(float f)
{
    union { float f; uint32_t x; } u = { f };
    return (u.x << 1) == 0xff000000u;
}

inline int isinf(double d)
{
    union { double d; uint64_t x; } u = { d };
    return (u.x << 1) == 0xff70000000000000ull;
}
```

You can also merge `isnan` and `isinf`.

Comment: For isnan and isinf above, it shoudld be 0xffe0000000000000ull instead of 0xff70000000000000ull.