# Do not allow additon of more elements into a vector

Tags: c++, stl, c++14, stdvector

I need to reserve x number of elements in a `std::vector`, say 10. Then I need to write some y number of values into it, say 5 (most of the time y < x). Is there a way to say how many values have been written to it and how may are still available?

Example:
Say I allocate 10 elements

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
```

But I only fill 7 of these elements

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i<7; i++)
  v[i] = i;
```

How can I tell that 7 elements have been filled and I still have 3 available?

I tried running
`v.size()` and `v.capacity()` but both return 10.

Comment: Consider using `std::vector::reserve` and `std::vector::push_back` methods.

Comment: *But I only fill 7 of these elements* -- What is your definition of "fill"?  You declared a vector of 10 elements, all initialized to 0.  If you want a vector with only 7 items, then create a vector with only 7 items.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie My motivation is to reserve some space for some maximum number of elements. Actual number of elements can be less than maximum but never more. When I reserve 10 elements, I don't necessarily care if they are initialized to 0, but once I start inserting elements I want to know how many I've inserted.

Comment: You didn't do any inserts in your example.  Those "inserts" have already been done in the constructor.  You construct a vector of 10 elements, you get 10 elements, so of course `v.size()` returns 10.  Maybe your idea of what a vector is seems to be a bit flawed.

Comment: *But I only fill 7 of these elements*  Nope. You *modify* 7 of these elements. `=` stands for assignment here. Assignment does not create, allocate, fill, ... its left hand side. It gives a new value to a thing that already exists.

Comment: `std::vector` is not designed to do that. You can **use** `std::vector` in your own class, and add all the frills that you want, while the vector member holds the data and manages its storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I added a method using `std::unique_ptr`.

---

If C++17 is available to you, how about replacing `v`'s elements by `std::optional<int>` as follows ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::optional<int>> v(10);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i<7; ++i){
        v[i] = i;
    }

    std::cout 
        << (v.size() - std::count(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), std::nullopt))
        << " elements have been filled and I still have "
        << std::count(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), std::nullopt) 
        << " available."
        << std::endl << std::endl;

    for(const auto v_i : v)
    {
        if(v_i.has_value()){        
            std::cout << v_i.value() << " ";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

But if you are constrained by an older version, I think that `std::unique_ptr` would be a solution.
[DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/E9xJvopImli9x3cy):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v(10);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i<7; ++i){
        v[i] = std::make_unique<int>(i);
    }

    std::cout 
        << (v.size() - std::count(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), nullptr))
        << " elements have been filled and I still have "
        << std::count(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), nullptr) 
        << " available."
        << std::endl << std::endl;

    for(const auto& v_i : v)
    {
        if(v_i){        
            std::cout << *v_i << " ";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Finally, I found similar approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033337/best-alternative-to-stdoptional-to-return-an-optional-value-from-a-method-us).

Comment: I really like this solution, but there is a caveat, which I forgot to mention. I'm constrained by C++14

Comment: Thx. It's my pleasure. Oh...I understand. I'll think about it.

Comment: @flashburn Although I don’t know whether it is preferred or not in this case, I added another solution using `std::unique_ptr` and a reference to similar approaches.

Comment: `boost::optional` is available in C++14.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?

```
std::vector<int> a; // dont allocate anything

// allocate memory for 10 elements, 
// but dont actually create them. a.size() is still 0.
a.reserve(10); 

for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
    // copy i to a new element at the back 
    // of the vector. This will never reallocate 
    // memory, as long as at most 10 elements 
    // are pushed:
    a.push_back(i); 
}
// a.size() is now 7
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to reserve x number of elements in a `std::vector`, say 10.

`std::vector` has a `reserve()` method for that exact purpose.

> Then I need to write some y number of values into it, say 5 (most of the time y < x). Is there a way to say how many values have been written to it and how may are still available?

The vector's `capacity()` is the number of elements have been allocated total, whereas its `size()` is the number of allocated elements that have been populated with values. So, `capacity() - size()` is the number of available elements that have been allocated but not assigned.

> I tried running `v.size()` and `v.capacity()` but both return 10.

That is because you are calling the `vector` constructor that allocates AND populates elements at the same time.  You are creating a `vector` named `v` that has 10 elements populated with 0. That is why `size()` and `capacity()` are both 10.  None of the constructors will do what you want. You need to use the default constructor and then call `reserve()` separately, eg:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(10); // capacity = 10

for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
    v.push_back(i);

size_t filled = v.size(); // size = 7
size_t available = v.capacity() - v.size(); // available = 3
```