# isnan does not work correctly with `-Ofast` flags

Tags: c++, gsl

Consider the following test program:

```
# include <gsl/gsl_statistics_double.h>
# include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double y = 50.2944, yc = 63.2128;
  double pearson_corr = gsl_stats_correlation(&y, 1, &yc, 1, 1);
  cout << "pearson_corr = " << pearson_corr << endl;
  if (isnan(pearson_corr))
    cout << "It is nan" << endl;
  else
    cout << "Not nan" << endl;
}
```

In some way, this code is some absurd, but its purpose is to show a subtle error that I am experiencing.

The call to `gsl_stats_correlation()` should give an error because the number of samples is 1 and the pearson coefficient has sense for at least two samples.

When I compile thus:

```
c++ test-r2.cc -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

the programs prints out `-nan` as result and the message "It is nan", which I consider correct because as I said it is not possible to compute the coefficient. The call to `isnan()`detects correctly that the result is `nan`. However, when I compile thus:

```
c++ -Ofast test-r2.cc -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

The program prints out `-nan` as result but the message "Not nan", which suggests that the call to `isnan()` was unable to detect the invalidity of `pearson_corr` variable.

So, my first question es "Why with the `-Ofast` flag the call to `isnan()` is not able to detect that the variable is `nan`. And my second question would be how to solve this problem in a way independent on the optimizations flags given to the compiler?

I am using gnu c++ version 5.4.0 on ubuntu 16.04 and an Intel i5 run at 64 bits mode

Thanks in advance

Comment: "fast-math can result in incorrect output for programs that depend on an exact implementation of IEEE or ISO rules/specifications for math functions", from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944614/is-it-possible-to-make-isnan-work-in-gfortran-o3-ffast-math

Comment: Check the value of `fpclassify(pearson_corr)` in both cases.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`-Ofast`, among other things, activates GCC's `-ffast-math` mode, and `-ffast-math`, among other things, causes the compiler to generate code that assumes that NaN (and Inf) never occur.

Therefore, if you need to use NaN or Inf, you *must not* use `-Ofast`.  There is no workaround.

Nearly all programs are better served by `-O2 -march=native` anyway; `-Ofast` turns on extremely aggressive inlining and loop unrolling that, in my experience, almost always blow the I-cache and make the program **slower**.

Comment: agreed: `-O2` is the best compromise. `-O3` / `-Ofast` is for _real_ players :) better optimize the code manually rather than relying on some magical option

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It _can_ be useful to apply `-O3` to a carefully selected subset of a complex program's source files, the ones with the hottest inner loops. It's true that a human assembly wizard can often do even better, but they're hard to come by and they don't work cheap. :)

Comment: agreed. not to mention that the code becomes non-portable. and with all this pipelining & cache thing, the compilers usually knows better. The 68000 days are over (sigh :))

Answer (score 4):

`man gcc` says this:

```
   -Ofast
       Disregard strict standards compliance.  -Ofast enables all -O3 optimizations.  It also enables optimizations that are not valid for all standard-compliant programs.  It turns on -ffast-math
       and the Fortran-specific -fno-protect-parens and -fstack-arrays.
```

and this:

```
   -ffast-math
       Sets -fno-math-errno, -funsafe-math-optimizations, -ffinite-math-only, -fno-rounding-math, -fno-signaling-nans and -fcx-limited-range.

       This option causes the preprocessor macro "__FAST_MATH__" to be defined.

       This option is not turned on by any -O option besides -Ofast since it can result in incorrect output for programs that depend on an exact implementation of IEEE or ISO rules/specifications
       for math functions. It may, however, yield faster code for programs that do not require the guarantees of these specifications.
```

You are telling the compiler to ignore NaNs, among other strange species of a the floating-point family.  If you don't want the compiler to do that, tell it `-O2` or `-O3` instead.

Answer (score 3):

> -Ofast
>
> Disregard strict standards compliance. -Ofast enables all -O3 optimizations.
> It also enables optimizations that are not valid for all standard-compliant
> programs. **It turns on -ffast-math**

and in that case `isnan` doesn't work, as explained better here [Mingw32 std::isnan with -ffast-math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263404/mingw32-stdisnan-with-ffast-math)

(one of the answers contains an implementation which will work, but it's also possible to wrap `isnan` in a c file which isn't compiled with `-Ofast`)

Answer (score 1):

You told GCC to assume no NaNs, so it's assuming no NaNs. Any code that depends on NaNs is obviously not going to be reliable if you do that.

From the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html):

- -Ofast

  > Disregard strict standards compliance. -Ofast enables all -O3 optimizations. It also enables optimizations that are not valid for all standard-compliant programs. **It turns on -ffast-math** and the Fortran-specific -fstack-arrays, unless -fmax-stack-var-size is specified, and -fno-protect-parens.
- -ffast-math

  > Sets the options -fno-math-errno, -funsafe-math-optimizations, **-ffinite-math-only**, -fno-rounding-math, -fno-signaling-nans, -fcx-limited-range and -fexcess-precision=fast. ...
- -ffinite-math-only

  > Allow optimizations for floating-point arithmetic **that assume that arguments and results are not NaNs** or +-Infs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this option: `-Ofast -fno-finite-math-only`, so `isnan` still works.

Or, if you don't want to use `-fno-finithe-math-only`, but still want to detect NaN numbers, you can do it in a platform dependent way: implement your own `isnan` function.

For example, if you're on a IEEE-754 platform with floats 32-bit and  doubles 64-bit, you can do:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <string.h>

bool myIsnan(float v) {
    std::uint32_t i;
    memcpy(&i, &v, 4);
    return ((i&0x7f800000)==0x7f800000)&&(i&0x7fffff);
}

bool myIsnan(double v) {
    std::uint64_t i;
    memcpy(&i, &v, 8);
    return ((i&0x7ff0000000000000)==0x7ff0000000000000)&&(i&0xfffffffffffff);
}
```

Comment: A little explanation about your code would be welcomed!